# VB.NET Edit and Continue how prevent dialog to popup every time had exception?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

On all version of VS (currently 2010), When Exception occur, the popup dialog appear and say:

the program is currently stopped at an exception. in order to make edit the state of the program must be reverted to just before the exception was thrown.

Edit, Stop, Cancel

How avoid this dialog, and get always Edit?

Comment: Tools + Options, Debugging, General, tick the "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions" option.  This is not always possible.

Comment: this option ticked already. So must be a reason that VS still not switch to edit mode Automatically?